# Wait for geolocation to return result before submitting form

Tags: jquery, forms, geolocation, location, form-submit

I am trying to fill city name in submit form if left emtpy. I have this code to get the city that the user is located.

```
    var form = $("form.js-reservation-form");
    form.submit(function(e) {        
            $.getJSON("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?jsoncallback=?", function(data) {
                console.log(data.geoplugin_city);
                $("input.geocity").val(data.geoplugin_city);       
            });
....
rest of code ....
});
```

The problem is that the form is submitted before the geocode returns the value. How can I change the code to wait first for the geoplugin to return value and then run the rest of code?

Comment: submit your form inside Call back function

Comment: Asynchronous request do not wait for the response , and start to execute the next statements

Answer (score 0):

I create fiddle to demonstrate how it works. Because of limitation i cant query you json, so i simulate it, to show how it works - https://jsfiddle.net/skyr9999/w5tun6nz/

Here is html:

```
<form class="js-reservation-form">
  <input class="geocity" type="input">
  <button type="button" id="submit-form">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and js

```
$(".js-reservation-form").click(function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/echo/json/",
        data: {"json": JSON.stringify({"geoplugin_city": "Magadan"})},
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.geoplugin_city);
            $("input.geocity").val(data.geoplugin_city);
            //$('form.js-reservation-form').submit();

        }});
});
```

So how it works - first of all there just ordinary button, and event that binds on it, then it do ajax query to get JSON, you can just use you URL and get rid of `data` if it not require. After JSON loaded value of city set for `input.geocity` and form submitted by jquery.

I comment submit code because it cause quick error, in you code you must uncomment this string `//$('form.js-reservation-form').submit();`